# Validation rule assistance

Tags: formula, validation

I'm looking for input on how to adjust an existing, working validation rule so that it doesn't fire when the running user is a specific Profile. 
Here is the existing rule:

```
AND( NOT(ISBLANK(Energy_Specialist__c)),
ISPICKVAL( Account.Audit_Provider__c , 'CET'),
NOT(ISPICKVAL( Energy_Specialist__r.Type__c, 'CET')))
```

I don't want it to fire for a specific Profile so I tried adding the last line below:

```
AND( NOT(ISBLANK(Energy_Specialist__c)),
ISPICKVAL( Account.Audit_Provider__c , 'CET'),
NOT(ISPICKVAL( Energy_Specialist__r.Type__c, 'CET')),
$User.ProfileId <> 00eM0000000QTa7  )
```

but I keep getting syntax errors saying I missing an ")" even after I add additional ending parenthesis. 
I'm also thinking that I might need to disclude more than 1 Profile in the future too.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you didn't use quotes (`''`) around the Profile Id.  Not that the error message gives you any insight into that, but thats whats causing the issue.    Try this

```
AND(
     NOT(ISBLANK(Energy_Specialist__c)),
     ISPICKVAL( Account.Audit_Provider__c , 'CET'),
     NOT(ISPICKVAL( Energy_Specialist__r.Type__c, 'CET')),
     $User.ProfileId <> '00eM0000000QTa7'
)
```

I would also recommend using the profile Name as opposed to the hardcoded ID.  Hardcoding IDs is never best practice.

```
$Profile.Name <> 'YOUR PROFILE NAME'
```

> EDIT

From your comment, if you want to add another excluded profile, just add another condition to the AND statement like below.

```
AND(
     NOT(ISBLANK(Energy_Specialist__c)),
     ISPICKVAL( Account.Audit_Provider__c , 'CET'),
     NOT(ISPICKVAL( Energy_Specialist__r.Type__c, 'CET')),
     $Profile.Name <> 'CORE Profile',
     $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator'
)
```

Comment: That was exactly it! I wanted to use the Profile name but when using the Insert field button/wizard, the User>Profile Name was not available, only ProfileID.

Comment: Yes, its not under user, its under profile when using the wizard.  Glad it worked for you.  :)

Comment: Would you know how I could set it to disclude 2 Profiles? I updated to not fire when a specific Profile Name as you stated and fired only when I expected which is great but when I added an or to it, it errors: AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Energy_Specialist__c)), 
ISPICKVAL( Contact.Account.Audit_Provider__c , 'CSG'), 
OR (NOT(ISPICKVAL( Energy_Specialist__r.Type__c, 'RTL'))), 
(NOT(ISPICKVAL( Energy_Specialist__r.Type__c, 'HES'))),
$Profile.Name <> "CORE Profile"  || "System Administrator")

Comment: Just updated the answer to reflect.